# How to add a Comment in Html dynamically using jquery or PHP and have that comment unremovable?

Tags: php, jquery, security, comments, web-deployment

I'm developing a website on PHP. I want to add a comment through jquery or php on every page like so:

```
< ! - -
 
developer name : Asad,

create date: 1/1/2014

-->
```

I want to know 2 things:

1. How can I do this?
2. If another developer edits my site, he wont able to remove my comment.

I used these 3 lines of code, but they fail:

First:

```
$('#id').html('<!--  test  -->');
```

or

```
$('#id').append('<!--  test  -->');
```

Then:

```
$('#id').before().html('<!--');
$('#id').after().html('-->');
```

These 2 code attempts failed.

**Update:**

I want to say that this comment is for use as my proof to show that this web site was developed by me.

I'm developing a web site. If in future a client wants to update his website and he contracts another developer, then maybe the other developer removes my name that is in the comment. So I want to secure that comment, so a new developer can't change it.

Comment: are the comments going to be dynamic? If not then why can't you add them directly through html ?

Comment: if a new developer edit my site so he wont able to remove my comment.. => can you explain more in details what you want !?

Comment: Its better you can use some thing like SVN in order to have a clear code changes...

Comment: Your first one ( `$('#id').html('<1!--  test  -->');` ) would work if you took out the '1' out of `<1!` as far as I can tell. Not that I think what you are doing makes much sense as you describe it.

Comment: i want to say that,,,that comment i use for my prove to show that this web is developing by me, detail:----  i'm developing a web site,, so in funture when clint want to update website so he contact to other developer,, then may me other developer remove my name that is in comment ,,, so i want to secure a comment that a new developer won't change it..

Comment: Gray sorry,... <1!-- test --> 1 enter by mistake... <!-- test --> is not working...

Comment: @user2511667 Oh ok. I think I see where the confusion was then. jQuery cannot modify the original HTML, only change the DOM. The comment gets added, but you can't see it by "viewing the source", only by inspecting the actual DOM.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to make it so future developer(s) are UNABLE to change it - possibly make it less likely sure but UNABLE not without obfuscating the code which isn't really possible with PHP or HTML. It is easy to add a line with PHP however the exact method kinda depends on how you are serving the files - if you have a single PHP header file for all (or most) of your files (very handy and the best way to do it IMO), then just add this to the top:

```
<?php
    echo "<--
        developer name : Asad,
        create date: $create_date
        -->";
 ?>
```

and for importing the header file in each file just do this:

```
<?php
    $create_date = 2014/01/01; //might ass well use the ISO standard: http://xkcd.com/1179/
    include "header.php"; (or whatever you have named it)
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as adding a comment via jQuery, you can view this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VHQ9F/) for an example. You should note that you can not see this change via "View Source" as this is the source that the server originally gave you. jQuery is only modifying the DOM, not the HTML. You can view this in most browsers via the DOM inspector (usually pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> shows this).

```
$('#id').html('<!--  here is a comment  -->');
$('#id').append('<!--  here is a another  -->');
```

As far as securing your page from being edited by other developers who have your code, this is not really possible. If they have the source, they can do anything with it including changing comments / etc. If you have some proprietary feature you want to hide, then you should do it server side. If it is some content like an image or video, then you can really only add a watermark to it.

Comment: gray really thank you,,, you give me solution and security,,, solution is that code,, and security is: comment not show in source code,,, so new developer will not see comment, so he don't think to remove comment... so when i want to show comment, i will show it by pressing f12

Answer (score 0):

In this example code, I have used jQuery AJAX for performing the add or delete comment actions. Finally, we can add some JavaScript to implement dynamic behavior - HTML and CSS, creating, removing and changing HTML, dynamically.